# How to provide an array of values as an env variable to typesafe/lightbend config?

Tags: scala, typesafe, typesafe-config

How do I provide an array/list of values as an environment variable to typesafe/lightbend config?

`application.conf`

```
default-buckets = [
      10,
      30,
      100,
      300,
      1000,
      3000,
      10000,
      30000,
      100000
    ]
default-buckets = [${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS}]
```

So, I'd like to pass something like this as an environment variable to be able to override the defaults:

```
DEFAULT_BUCKETS=1000,3000
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

`com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: env variables: buckets.default-buckets has type list of STRING rather than list of NUMBER`

Is this possible without having to have my application code deal with it by e.g. calling `split(',')`?

Comment: See also the reasoning on the answer to [HOCON array substitution from envs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416875/1159167)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there's no simple way to pass a list of environment variable to override an array of conf values.

You will have to set env vars like so:

```
export DEFAULT_BUCKETS_1=1000
export DEFAULT_BUCKETS_2=3000
```

Then pass them into the conf file:

```
default-buckets = []
default-buckets.0 = ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_1}
default-buckets.1 = ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_2}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as written due to https://gitter.im/lightbend/config?at=584045608d65e3830ec4b761
you would get "default-buckets has type OBJECT rather than LIST"

I worked around it in our application by setting
default-buckets.0 = ""
default-buckets.0 = ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_1}

then filtering the list in the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
default-buckets = [
  ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_1},
  ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_2},
  ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_3},
  ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_4},
  ${?DEFAULT_BUCKETS_5}
]
```

For

```
DEFAULT_BUCKETS_1=10
DEFAULT_BUCKETS_2=30
DEFAULT_BUCKETS_5=100
```

Results in

```
TestConfig(List(10, 30, 100))
```